# Predicted top rated recommended items by the trained Spark ALS model are not the collaborative ones

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-science, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I used an explicit ratings dataset that has around 389K ratings for 52K users and 100k items.

Basic stats:
Average number of ratings per item: 3.89
Average number of ratings per user: 7.45
Users with the fewest rating: 1
Item with the fewest rating: 2

The used ALS model with the following settings:

```
als = ALS(userCol="userId", itemCol="vidId", ratingCol="rate", rank=10, maxIter=15,
          regParam=0.15, coldStartStrategy="drop", nonnegative=True, implicitPrefs=False)
```

In validation, I used 80% for training and 20% for testing. 
The RMSE on the validation set is: 0.32 (it is very low)

In production, I used the whole dataset in training the ALS model (keeping same config as in validation)

To get the top 100 user-item recommendations for each user, I used the following instruction:

```
users_recommendation = model.recommendForAllUsers(100)
```

However, most of the times, the top recommended items are not coming from any collaborative users rated items.

According to my knowledge, top user-item recommended items should be come from from any collaborative users rated items.

Recommending items without any collaboration is meaningless.

Comment: Hii, I don't understand your question. Can I guess do you need help to get a more accurate model??

Comment: If you have a lower accuracy model. I suggest you make a feature engineering process first and then generate the `ALS Model`. Remember the als model is not more than a factorization matrix, so maybe there are so many null values. Also, I recommend you to use `mse` which is more accurate with ml models like this. You should also try to understand the tendency of the scores.

Comment: Hi  @Kenry Sanchez, I used RMSE and it is 0.32 (so far not bad). I did some basic feature engineering that I mentioned at very beginning. My question is about the collaborations among the users of the predicted top rated items and the tested user. I don't see any direct collaborations between users of the predicted top rated items and the tested user. I did not check indirect collaborations among them yet.

Comment: Hi @KenrySanchez , I found the reason. It was the sparsity problem of our data. Literature is saying maximum sparsity, about 99.5% [sparsity](https://jessesw.com/Rec-System/). The sparsity of the used data, was 99.9%. After reducing sparsity, it is now working.

Comment: thank you so much for share the insight with me.